# Синтаксис вызова функции указателем

Tags: c

Меня мучает вопрос, с какой целью это сделано?

Есть такой указатель: `int (*a)() = ownfucntion; /// ownfucntion - любая пользовательская функция.`

Мы можем эту функцию вызвать так: `a();`

А можем так: `(*a)();`

Где логика? Обычно разименовывание используется для получения значения из указателя. А тут результат одинаков: хочешь разименовывай, хочешь не разименовывай в итоге будет вызвана функция.

Comment: *с какой целью это сделано?* вряд ли можно получить однозначный (читай: "объективно верный ответ") ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut с целью узнать, очевидно же =)

Comment: Это была цитата из Вашего вопроса. Я хочу сказать, что только авторы дизайна языка могут дать ответ на этот вопрос. Остальное будет лишь догадками. То есть, формально, Ваш вопрос - оффтопик.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обозначение функции всегда за исключением одного случая преобразуется в указатель на функцию.

Из стандарта C (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
>   Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
>   operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
>   is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
>   returning type’’.

Хотя в этой цитате написано про использование оператора `sizeof`, но на самом деле функция не может использоваться в операторе `sizeof`.

Стандарт C (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 1 The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
>   a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-ﬁeld member

Поэтому когда используется постфиксное выражение вызова функции, то обозначение функции неявно преобразуется к указателю на функцию (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 1 The expression that denotes the called function92) shall have type
>   pointer to function returning void or returning a complete object type
>   other than an array type.

В связи с этим можно написать даже такое выражение, как показано в следующей демонстрационной программе

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void )
{
    puts( "Oh...At last I am called!" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    ( **********f)();

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Oh...At last I am called!
```

Потому что согласно стандарту C (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand
>   has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undeﬁned.102

То есть сначала обозначение функции преобразуется неявно к указателю на функцию. Затем после применения оператора `*` этот указатель преобразуется к обозначению функции и сразу же снова преобразуется в указатель на функцию и т.д.

Вы можете применить столько операторов `*` к обозначению функцию, сколько позволит конкретный компилятор

---

Подытоживая, можно сказать следующее. Для объявления функций вводится их идентификатор, чтобы по нему можно было ссылаться на функции и отличать одну функцию от другой. При этом сама функция может быть еще не определена, а лишь только объявлена.

Когда этот идентификатор функции или, другими словами, обозначение функции используется в выражениях, то оно преобразуется к типу указателя на функцию.

В выражениях используются значения. Какое значение назначить обозначению функции, используемому в выражениях?

Естественно разумно в качестве значения использовать адрес функции, потому что все, для чего создаются функции, это для их выполнения. А выполнить функцию можно, лишь передав управление по тому адресу, где эта функция определена.

Поэтому в качестве значения функции и принят ее адрес, то есть функция в выражениях преобразуется к указателю на саму себя.

Единственным исключением по отношению к неявному преобразования функции к указателю на функцию является использование оператора &. Здесь нет необходимости преобразовывать функцию неявно к указателю на нее, так как применение оператора & итак является явным взятием адреса функции.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53503/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow----).

Answer (score 10):

В стандартном С вызов функции вообще *всегда* делается именно и только через *указатель* на функцию, т.е. оператор `()` требует именно указательного операнда. А тип "функция" во всех контекстах, кроме `sizeof`, `_Alignof` и унарного `&`, автоматически неявно преобразуется к типу "указатель на функцию" (явление, часто называемое *function type decay*).

Таком образом даже когда вы пишете `ownfunction()` на самом деле происходит неявное преобразование `(int (*)()) ownfunction` и оператор `()` применяется уже именно к результату этого преобразования.

Попытка явного применения унарного оператора `*` к указателю на функцию приводит к тому, что результат этого применения (типа "функция") сразу же снова автоматически "сваливается" обратно в тип "указатель" (за исключением вышеупомянутых контекстов). А отсюда уже побочным эффектом следует как возможность опционального/"бесконечного" применения унарного оператора `*` к указателю на функцию, так и опциональность применения унарного оператора `&` при явном получении указателя на функцию.

(Т.е. для иллюстрации этого поведения оператора `*` совсем не обязательно заводить явный указатель `a` на функцию. Оно прекрасно иллюстрируется на примере самой функции.)

P.S. Ситуация во многом симметрична ситуации с массивами (*array type decay*), с той только разницей, что массив неявно преобразуется к типу "указатель на элемент", а не "указатель на весь массив", что предотвращает возможность "бесконечного" применения унарного оператора `*` к массиву. Но общая идея - та же.

---

Что интересно, в доисторических версиях языка С (см. ["C Reference Manual"](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf)) Деннис Ритчи определял поведение оператора `()` именно и только через тип "функция", т.е. слева от `()` должно было указываться именно выражение типа "функция", а не "указатель на функцию". И именно в этом контексте неявного преобразования типа "функция" к типу "указатель на функцию" не происходило. Это где-то позже (в K&R C?) оператор `()` вдруг стал требовать операнда типа "указатель на функцию".

Почему произошел такой переход? Трудно сказать. Возможно авторов языка привлекла возможность унификации *function type decay* с *array type decay*. На это также неявно указывает то, что в список контекстов-исключений включили оператор `sizeof`, тем самым сделав выражение `sizeof функция` нелегальным. Казалось бы, зачем было включать `sizeof` в список исключений? Можно было бы разрешить *function type decay* под `sizeof` и `sizeof функция` спокойно возвращало бы размер указателя на функцию. Но нет. Вероятная причина - унификация decay-поведения с массивами.

Comment: Хм...а что вы скажете на это: a - указатель на функцию. Если его распечатать через printf `%p` то мы получим адрес. И этот адрес мы получим и так `a` и так `*a`. Почему указатель имеет и в значении и в разименовании одно и тоже значение?

Comment: @MaximPro: В моем ответе выше именно об этом и говорится. Выражение `*a` имеет тип "функция", который сразу же снова автоматически приводится обратно к типу "указатель", как будто оператора `*` и не было. Поэтому `a` эквивалентно `*a` (и `**a`, и `***a` и т.д.) почти во всех контекстах. Все.

Comment: выходит лучше использовать вызов функции через указатель без астерикса?

Comment: @MaximPro, с точки зрения читаемости кода - да (но дело вкуса). С точки зрения эффективности кодогеренации - без разницы.

Comment: @AnT Это выносит мне мозг. Хмм то есть можно сказать что `printf` - это идентификатор функции. Если мы пишем так `printf()` то мы преобразуем неявно идентификатор в указатель который требуют `()`. В итоге допустим я понимаю что если написать `&printf` - этим мы получим адрес то есть указатель. А вот что будет так `*printf` я не понимаю... ну как мы можем получить доступ к данным косвенностью к не указателю? Я бы понял это только в том случае если вы printf перед * привелась бы к указателю, а потом бы выполнилась бы *, которая ............ что? что? что? что происходит тут?

Comment: Либо  операцией * мы получаем тот же адрес (который записывается и в указатель и в адрес указателя)? Либо при использование * к указателю на функцию блокируется эта операция и мы получаем то же самое что и без *. Тут мне нужно более точное пояснение момента.

Comment: `function type decay` - что это? я не понял...

Comment: @MaximPro: "Function type decay" - это полу-формальное название почти-всегда происходящего неявного автоматического преобразования типа "функция" к типу "указатель на функцию".

Comment: @ant а выше я еще спрашивал?

Comment: @MaximPro: "Function type decay" не происходит в контекстах операторов `&` и `sizeof`. Это контексты-исключения. Поэтому в `&printf` мы получаем именно адрес функции (а не попытку сформировать "указатель на указатель"). А оператор `*` - не исключение. Поэтому в `*printf` сначала происходит "function type decay", т.е. неявное преобразование `printf` к указателю, а затем уже к этому указателю применяется оператор `*`. Результатом `*` становится "функция", которая тут же снова неявно преобразуется к указателю. Т.е. в результате получается так, как будто оператора `*` не было вообще.

Comment: То есть если я в коде напишу, `printf;`(как отдельную строчку кода) то это обозначение функции будет приведено автоматически к указателю? без всяких звезд и скобок?

Comment: @MaximPro: Формально - да, именно так. Хотя это феномен из разряда "Слышен ли звук падающего дерева в лесу, если рядом никого нет?". То же самое происходит и с именем массива `array;`. Происходит автоматическое приведение к указателю, хотя это никому не нужно и ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Тогда как это связано с преобразованием имени массива? Я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: @MaximPro: Связано *внешним сходством* и больше ничем. Подробно все описано выше.

Comment: Откуда появился термин `оператор ()`? Не вижу такого оператора в стандарте сей.

Comment: @alexolut: См. **6.5.2 Postfix operators**. Также в индексе **function-call operator (( )), 6.5.2.2**.

Comment: @AnT хм-м... при этом упоминания вида `operator()` или `()operator` в тексте не наблюдается, в отличии от других операторов.

Comment: @alexolut: Это непринципиально. Понятно, что этот оператор ведет себя несколько "необычно" по сравнению с другими операторами. Вполне может быть, что стандарт языка по этой причине не хочет называть его "оператором" в нормативном тексте. Но это не отменяет устоявшиеся терминологии. Точно так же мы пользуемся термином "переменная" ("variable"), хотя стандарт языка тщательно избегает использования этого термина в нормативном тексте, за исключением библиотечных разделов про "atomic variables". (Хотя здесь это скорее неделимое словосочетание.)

Answer (score 1):

Выполняется неявное приведение. Имя функции и ее адрес полностью взаимозаменяемы, а соответственно, вытекает и необходимость возможности применения `&` (и `*`) к имени и к адресу функции.

Например, допустимы оба варианта:

```
int (*a)() = ownfucntion;
int (*a)() = &ownfucntion;
```

Ну, а вызывать можете даже так :)

```
(********************&********************a)();
```

Comment: если честно ничего не понял, а про то что можно писать `&ownfucntion` и так `ownfucntion` очевидно исходя из того что имя является адресом как и имя массива адрес